# Extract images and ID's with Simple PHP DOM Parser and output them each in array

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domparser

I'm super new to DOM but I see it's very powerful and might work for what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically, I want to fetch images from site and their corresponding ID's.
Then I want to put each image with it's own ID in table, not just outputting them as text.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<?php

// Include the php dom parser    
include 'parser.php';

$url = 'https://www.example.com/images.php?p=1';

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo $element->src, '<br />';
}

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    echo $element->ID, '<br />';
}
?>
```

and the example output is:

img1.jpg
img2.jpg
img3.jpg
id1
id2
id3

I want to associate the rows in a tables (img1 with id1, img2 with id2, etc...) and output the image next to the ID in table.

How would I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do these images+A links share the same parent element? If do so, first select the parent element, then run your logic for parent element found.

If your html structure is like:

```
<div><img /> <a>link</a></div>


foreach($html->find('div') as $div) {

    foreach($div->find('img') as $image) {
        echo $image->src, '<br />';
    }

    foreach($div->find('a') as $link) {
        echo $link->ID, '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not unfortunately. :(